# using and meaning of " that"

Tags: grammar

According to the following paragraph what is the difference between the first " that" and the second "that" grammatically?
Do they have the same meaning?

> Artists tell me that for a deep and true appreciation of art one must educate the eye. One must learn from experience to weigh the merits of line, of composition, of form and color. If I had eyes, how happily would I embark upon so fascinating a study! Yet I am told that, to many of you who have eyes to see, the world of art is a dark night, unexplored and unilluminated."

Three Days to See, by Helen Keller

Answer (score 1):

They both have the same function. The word order is somewhat convoluted, which makes the function a bit obscure. Perhaps this rewording will help:

> Artists tell me that one must educate the eye [if one is to have] a deep and true appreciation of art...I am told that the world of art is a dark night.

The word order that Keller uses makes for richer and more colorful prose, but it's a bit difficult to parse out.